# Creating a list using private variables in a class

Tags: python, list, class, oop, getter-setter

I am creating a class called `Pet`. I am making my variables private so no one can modify them (ensuring encapsulation). I want to create a list using private variables.
Then I want to be able to call my `pet_list` list *outside* the class where I will be using it for a later purpose (would I need to create a getter for my list inside the `Pet` class to do this?).

I am new to python but I'm trying to code using the object orientated principles.

This is my code so far.
I'm thinking because my `pet` variable is private I need to use a setter to set the `Pet`s in the list? But I get this error when I want to print `set_pet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pet'`.

```
class Pet:
      def __init__(self, pet ):
          self.pet = pet

      def set_pet(self, pet):
         self.__pet = pet

      def get_pet(self):
         return self.__pet


#creating list

pet_list = []

p = Pet

pet_list.append(p.set_pet("cat"))
pet_list.append( Pet("dogs"))
pet_list.append( Pet("fish"))
pet_list.append( Pet("horses"))
pet_list.append( Pet("birds"))

for obj in pet_list:
    print(obj.pet)
```

Comment: `p = Pet("cat")`? `p = Pet` just gives you an alias for the class. It's not clear why you create that one differently to the others you're putting in the list. Also you need `get_pet` (or read about `@property`) at the end.

Comment: No, it's *not* creating an instance - you need *parentheses* to call the class to get an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at `p = Pet`. Here you are not initializing an instance of the **class** `Pet` but you are instead setting `p` equal to the class. Instead use

```
p = Pet("The pet you want")
```

The reason you are getting the errror `set_pet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pet'` is because `"cat"` is being passed as a positional argument in the place of `self` and thus it is as if you passed only 1 argument.

Also, `pet_list.append(p.set_pet("cat"))` would append `None` into the list since you are only setting the property and not returning anything, all the other's should work fine as expected.

Comment: Yes I understand now! I changed the code to what you said and it works now, thank you :)